# DocuSign get signing URL for existing envelopes

Tags: xml, docusignapi

I successfully create an envelope and provide an embedded signing URL. **Is there a way to provide that same URL after the envelope has already been created?** My goal is provide a link where signers are able to view their envelope at anytime.

Comment: Why not just generate the URL when it's requested?  It takes 1-2 seconds to create, and that way you don't have to manage a bunch of URL tokens and you don't have to worry about them expiring so often.

Comment: If that's not an option for some reason then just generate a URL token for a given user, and since it expires after 5 mins just generate a new one at 4:50 or so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can get a "fresh" URL that will launch the envelope documents (in view-only mode, assuming the recipient has previously completed signing) by simply issuing another "**POST Recipient View**" REST API call for that recipient.  DocuSign will know that the recipient has already completed signing, so the Envelope will open in read-only mode when you launch the URL returned in the **POST Recipient View** response.

Keep in mind that each URL retrieved with the "**POST Recipient View**" request only works for a certain amount of time (5 minutes?) after you retrieve it -- so you'll want to not make the API call to get the URL until the time at which the signer has indicated that they want to view their envelope...then once received in the **POST Recipient View** response, immediately use that URL to launch the envelope.

Comment: I was able to do this for the first recipient who has a clientUserId. When I try this for he remaining recipients who do not have this parameter it returns an error saying one of the values does not match.

Comment: The "POST Recipient View" request will only return a successful response for "embedded/captive" recipients -- i.e., recipients for whom you specified "clientUserId" property when creating the envelope.  If you want to display Envelope documents for non-embedded/captive recipients, then "POST Recipient View" is not the way to accomplish that -- you'd instead want to issue a "GET Envelope Documents" request...the response will contain a byte stream representing the document(s), and your app can use that to display docs in the browser.